# MYSQL - join table on different conditions (is null and is not null) without union

Tags: mysql, join, yii

```
table1
---+---------
id | value
---+---------
1  | (NULL)
2  | 'string'
3  | (NULL)

table2
---+-----------
id | table1_id
---+-----------
1  | 3
```

I can get my result by executing

```
select table1.id from table1 where table1.value is not null
union
select table1.id from table1 right join table2 on table1.id=table2.table1_id
```

So What I need to get is

```
---+--
id | 
---+--
2  |
3  |
```

But i can't use union because i should use yii1.1 CDbCriteria which does not support union
I've tried different join types but no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your query this way using a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM
  table1 LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.id=table2.table1_id
WHERE
  table1.value IS NOT NULL
  or table2.table1_id IS NOT NULL
```

since you are using a LEFT JOIN, table2.table1_id will be null when the join does not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a join at all, this simple query should do it:

> select id from table1 where value is not null or id in (select
>   distinct table1_id from table2)